# Is it possible to schedule a job with Google Data Fusion and then delete the developer instance?

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm evaluating Google Cloud Data Fusion to use for an internal project, and I want to be able to set up a Data Fusion instance, define and deploy a scheduled pipeline, then shut down the Data Fusion instance. However, when the instance is shut down, I still want the scheduled pipeline to keep running on schedule. Is this possible?

I've read through the Google Data Fusion documentation and understand how to set up a scheduled pipeline but I'm unclear on how that pipeline, once created, is tied to the instance. Some of the documentation makes it sound like "operations" and "instances" are separate entities, which makes me think what I want to do may be possible, but I'm still unclear as to how to make that happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data Fusion has an inbuilt scheduler that triggers pipelines, the Data Fusion instance needs to be running for the scheduler to run the pipelines periodically.